# How performing these two function?

Tags: php, regex

is possible perform these two function converting in a regular expression?

```
// Get all alpha-substring to left and before of any digits
// otherwise return empty string.
function ex1($source) {
  $string_alpha = "";
  $tmp = substr($source, 0, strcspn($source, '0123456789'));
  if (ctype_alpha($tmp)) { 
    $string_alpha = $tmp;
  }
  return $string_alpha;
}

// Get all numeric-substring to right and after last letter
// otherwise return empty string.
function ex2($source) {
  $string_numeric = "";
  $tmp = substr($source, strcspn($source, '0123456789'));
  if (ctype_digit($tmp)) { 
    $string_numeric = $tmp;
  }
  return $string_numeric;
}

$source = "butterfly12";
echo "ex1 function => " . ex1($source) . "<br>";
echo "ex2 function => " . ex2($source) . "<br>";

// Output:
// ex1 function => butterfly
// ex2 function => 12
```

I have tried to code about i need to do with these two example.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes. What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to capture them in your functions.

Regex for capturing the letters:

`/([A-Z]+)/i`

Regex for capturing the numbers:

`/([0-9]+)/`

So you could have functions like:

```
function getAlpha($source) {
   preg_match("/([A-Z]+)/i", $source, $matches);
   return $matches[1];
}

function getNumeric($source) {
   preg_match("/([0-9]+)/", $source, $matches);
   return $matches[1];
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
echo getAlpha("butterfly12"); //butterfly
echo getNumeric("butterfly12"); //12
```

**EDIT**

I now think I understand what you mean, perhaps these functions would work best for you:

```
function getAlpha($source) { //Gets whatever text is before a number.
    $alpha = "";
    if(preg_match("/^([A-Z]+)\d+/i", $source, $matches)) {
        $alpha = $matches[1];
    }
    return $alpha;
}

function getNumeric($source) { //Gets whatever number is after the text.
    $numeric = "";
    if(preg_match("/(\d+)$/", $source, $matches)) {
        $numeric = $matches[1];
    }
    return $numeric;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this i know, but into two example i don't capture simply a substring but i validate it too with specific condition. For this i asked.

Comment: I have updated my example. That code will work as intended.

Comment: It not work correctly. For example if the string begin with a number function ex1() return a empty string and getAlpha() return the Alpha-string. failing the validation.
Me not need extract simply a numeric / Alpha string. Thanks again.

Comment: So what do you want? If the string starts with a number, then what? If it starts with a string, then what? Please be clear or I can't help.

Comment: I asking if possible convert exactely the ex1() and ex2() function in a regular expression which work exactely as work ex1() and ex2() function. 
For to be more right i wrote the two function for this reason. So is more right as should work the regular expression.
The ex1() and ex2() function not capture only a Alpha-substring or numeric-substring but do a validation.